# Aggregation function to get the difference or ratio of two rows in order

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

I have a table full of prices, items, and dates. An example of this is:

```
AA, 1/2/3024, 1.22
AA, 1/3/3024, 1.23
BB, 1/2/3024, 4.22
BB, 1/3/3024, 4.23
```

Within the data there are only two rows per price, and they are ordered by date. How would I condense this data set into a single product row showing the difference from the last price to the previous? [Also this applies to a ratio, so AA would produce 1.23/1.22].

The result should look like

```
AA, todays price-yesterdays price
```

Despite being a sum function, there is no subtraction function over a list.

I'm using postgres 9.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select product,
       sales_date,
       current_price - prev_price as diff
from (
  select product,
         sales_date, 
         price as current_price,
         lag(price) over (partition by product order by sales_date) as prev_price,
         row_number() over (partition by product order by sales_date desc) as rn
  from the_unknown_table
) t
where rn = 1;
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9f7d6/1

Comment: It took me a while to understand what the row number was needed for but now I understand

Comment: Third comment.. but thats rather clever about the use of order by and order by desc. I thought it was a mistake at first.

Answer (score 3):

Since `there are only two rows per price`, this can be *much* simpler and faster:

```
SELECT n.item, n.price - o.price AS diff, n.price / o.price AS ratio
FROM   price n                 -- "new"
JOIN   price o USING (item)    -- "old"
WHERE  n.day > o.day;
```

[**->SQLfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c3b12/1)

This form carries the additional benefit, that you can use all columns from both rows directly.

---

For **more complex scenarios** (not necessary for this), you could use window functions as has been pointed out. Here is a simpler approach than what has been suggested:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (item)
       item
      ,price - lead(price) OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY day DESC) AS diff
FROM   price
ORDER  BY item, day DESC;
```

Only one window function is needed here. And one query level, since [`DISTINCT ON`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564) is applied *after* window functions. The sort order in the window agrees with overall sort order, helping performance.

Answer (score 1):

If there's only two rows per item, then

```
SELECT item, MAX(price) - MIN(price) AS diff, MAX(price) / MIN(price) AS ratio
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY item
```

will do the trick.

Comment: That won't work bescause the difference must be based on the date. Aka  today's price - yesterday's price.