# Calculating the difference between two values from an item in history

Tags: sql, postgresql

Situation:

I have this table where I load items into a history, more or less like below:

```
| date                | item | value |
|---------------------|------|-------|
| 2018-03-08 10:22:00 |   A  | 300   |
| 2018-03-08 10:22:00 |   B  | 3000  |
| 2018-03-08 10:22:00 |   C  | 30    |
| 2018-03-08 10:21:00 |   A  | 200   |
| 2018-03-08 10:21:00 |   B  | 2000  |
| 2018-03-08 10:21:00 |   C  | 20    |
| 2018-03-08 10:20:00 |   A  | 100   |
| 2018-03-08 10:20:00 |   B  | 1000  |
| 2018-03-08 10:20:00 |   C  | 10    |
```

And I need to calculate the differences between a item entry with the previous item entry, progamatically, resulting in

```
| date                | item | value | diff |
|---------------------|------|-------|------|
| 2018-03-08 10:22:00 |   A  | 300   | 100  |
| 2018-03-08 10:22:00 |   B  | 3000  | 1000 |
| 2018-03-08 10:22:00 |   C  | 30    | 10   |
| 2018-03-08 10:21:00 |   A  | 200   | 100  |
| 2018-03-08 10:21:00 |   B  | 2000  | 1000 |
| 2018-03-08 10:21:00 |   C  | 20    | 10   |
| 2018-03-08 10:20:00 |   A  | 100   | 100  |
| 2018-03-08 10:20:00 |   B  | 1000  | 1000 |
| 2018-03-08 10:20:00 |   C  | 10    | 10   |
```

I had saw [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20275190/aggregation-function-to-get-the-difference-or-ratio-of-two-rows-in-order), and that sounded promising, but what I need is one that could build this historical series, because this value will be used into some Grafana dashboards for graphics... Any tips on how I could do this?

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.3 on Linux on System z

Comment: The linked answer seems to solve your problem. Why isn't it working for you? `lag()` is the best solution to this.

Comment: Using the linked solution, it gave me just the last value... What I need is one that calculate all the series, or at least a part of (maybe somewhat 1k lines for each series)